# Update database struct when Rails association changes

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Which is the best way to do database migration when association changes?

For example:

Add has_one/ has_many/ & belongs_to association to 2 models have no association.

Add has_many_and_belongs_to association to 2 models have no association.

Add has_one/ has_many/ & belongs_to association to 2 models that one model have association with other model, another model is newly created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When your association changes, is it not just that you have to change the foreign keys in the db scheme and create specific migrations for that?

For example if you want to add a has_many relationship to *store* which has many *books*. You could easily create a migration with the *generate* command.

```
rails g migration addStoreIdToBooks store_id:integer
```

Then in your **model/store.rb**

```
has_many :books
```

And in the **model/book.rb**

```
belongs_to :store
```

Otherwise I didn't understand your question :)